# SDL_CreateRenderer() vs SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer()

Tags: c, graphics, sdl, sdl-2, renderer

Does a renderer created with `SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer()` behave any differently than one created with `SDL_CreateRenderer()` using the `SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE` flag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are differences on how these two operate, or even their intended use. `SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer` creates software renderer drawing to given surface. There is no requirement for this surface to be window surface, you can draw to backbuffer, convert it to texture and feed the result to d3d or opengl renderer.

`SDL_CreateRenderer` creates renderer for a given window, meaning it is supposed to draw to that window - with some checks, like opengl or vulkan requires window to be created with specific flags. It goes through list of available rendering backends and tries to find the one that matches your `flags` the best. Eventually if it decides to use software renderer (either nothing else is supported or software is explicitly requested, although there is more than one way to do so - see the last paragraph) it [calls](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/05aff4771d9a/src/render/software/SDL_render_sw.c#l823) more-or-less `SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer(SDL_GetWindowSurface(window))` (not exactly so, but if you'll trace the code it is the same).

`flags` in `SDL_CreateRenderer` are not absolute; if a [hint](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryHints) says to use direct3d or opengl, your `SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE` will be ignored. `SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer` is always software.

Answer (score 1):

Nope! They should behave the same.

SDL2 has quite a list of convenience functions which are equivalent to simply calling another function with a specific set of arguments. For instance, looking at the [API listing by name](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryAPI), you'll find that the `SDL_LogMessage ()` function is matched with a variety of other functions that implicitly specify the `priority` field, like `SDL_LogVerbose ()` or `SDL_LogError ()`.

To some extent, in addition to providing ease-of-use, these combined convenience functions help provide brevity to code while still maintaining clarity. As such, I would advise and advocate for their use when possible!